# NHibernate Get() followed by Flush or Commit?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, unit-of-work, flush

My ISession object's FlushMode is FlushMode.Commit.

I use the unit of work and repository pattern as defined here:
http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx

I recall seeing some examples where some people call a Get() immediately followed by a Flush or a transaction commit. We're they just off their rocker, or is there a reason to do this?

From my test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Employee e;

        IRepository<Employee> empRepo;
        using(UnitOfWork.Start(Enums.Databases.MyDatabase))
        {
            empRepo = new Repository<Employee>();
            e = empRepo.GetByID(21);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(e.UserName);
    }
```

My GetByID repository function just calls Session.Get(id) and I can view the username in the output window (after the session is killed)... so whats the point of any sort of Flush or transaction commit after a Get() ? I would understand if there was a save in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate assumes that all database operations are done within transactions, so people use them explicitly instead of having <strike>NHibernate</strike> the RDBMS use them implicitly.

Ayende explains this in more detail in his post [NH Prof Alerts: Use of implicit transactions is discouraged](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx).

Edit: Learned something new today. It's not NHibernate using implicit transactions but the DB.

Comment: I think you mean..."instead of having `RDBMS` use them implicitly."

Comment: @dotjoe Actually, no. Maybe I am misunderstanding the concept but I was under the impression that if we don't explicitly use the transaction, NHibernate will execute every statement in its own transaction. That's what I meant when I wrote that NHibernate uses transactions implicitly.

Comment: If you're not in an explicit transaction then RDBMS will execute each individual statement in it's own transaction. I'm pretty sure NH doesn't create them for you...

Comment: dotjoe is correct (I believe). The RDBMS wraps everything in a transaction. NHibernate just allows you to specify what type of transaction - readcommitted, readuncommitted, etc - and also I believe it prevents round trips to the RDBMS by grouping queries toegether in a single transaction rather than multiple

Comment: @dotjoe @Chris Klepeis I see, then I did misunderstand the concept. I edited my post to fix that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Chris Klepeis it's up to you to limit the roundtrips to db. Using a transaction isn't going to put all the queries in one batch. You can use `MultiCriteria` or `Future` to batch queries and improve performance.